# How to modify a Meteor template when pressing a button?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

So I'm creating a simple poll app. I have a form that has 3 fields, for 3 answers for a question of the poll. What I would like to do is create a button so that I can create more fields dynamically when I need them.

But I'm confused about how to do this

```
<template name="pollForm">
  <form class="new-poll">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Question</label>
          <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Question">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Choice #1</label>
          <input type="text" name="choice1" placeholder="Choice #1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Choice #2</label>
          <input type="text" name="choice2" placeholder="Choice #2">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Choice #3</label>
          <input type="text" name="choice3" placeholder="Choice #3">
      </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

How can I modify the HTML of the template so I can add more fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a click event and append new HTML elements with JavaScript or jQuery:

```
 $('<div>').attr('class', 'form-group').insertBefore('#add-choice');
 $('<label>').text('Choice #1').appendTo('form div.form-group:last');
 $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').attr('name', 'choice1').attr('placeholder', 'Choice 1').appendTo('form div.form-group:last');
```

Another approach would be to use a local (client-side) Meteor collection and insert documents when clicking the button:

```
Choices = new Mongo.Collection(null);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.pollForm.events({
        'click #add-choice': function () {
            Choices.insert({'label': 'Choice #123', 'placeholder': 'Choice #123', 'name': "choice123"});
        }
    });
    Template.pollForm.helpers({
        choices: () => Choices.find()
    });
    Template.pollForm.onRendered(function () {
        Choices.insert({'label': 'Choice #1', 'placeholder': 'Choice #1', 'name': "choice1"});
        Choices.insert({'label': 'Choice #2', 'placeholder': 'Choice #2', 'name': "choice2"});
        Choices.insert({'label': 'Choice #3', 'placeholder': 'Choice #3', 'name': "choice3"});
    });
}
```

---

```
<template name="pollForm">
    <form class="new-poll">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Question</label>
            <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Your Question">
        </div>
        {{#each choices}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>{{label}}</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{name}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        <button type="button" id="add-choice">Add choice</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Please ask another question with the specific requirements and we'll try to help you.

Comment: Here you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975864/add-elements-to-collection-based-on-a-dynamic-template