# Add elements to collection based on a dynamic template

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I have a poll template that can have as many questions as the user wants. How do I insert all the questions into an element of a collection? Since I only had three before, I inserted them manually like this:

```
var newPoll = {
          question: event.target.question.value,
          choices: [
            {  text: event.target.choice1.value, votes: 0 },
            {  text: event.target.choice2.value, votes: 0 },
            {  text: event.target.choice3.value, votes: 0 }
          ],
          usersWhoVoted: [],
          poll_is_open: true,
          time_poll_closed: null,
 };
```

If I can have now as many choices as I want, how do I insert all of them?

Comment: Do you use a local collection?

Comment: It's just an array, so first identify it (`newPoll.question`), then add stuff to it (`newPoll.question.push({})`).

Comment: @MatthiasEckhart Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have implemented a local collection to store `Choices` related data, you could use the **[`cursor.map()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/)** function to loop over your collection, return proper objects into an array and finally set the corresponding data:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.pollForm.events({
        'click #save-form': function(event, template) {
            var choices = Choices.find().map((choice) => ({
                text: template.find("input[name=" + choice.name + "]").value,
                votes: 0
            }));
            var newPoll = {
                question: event.target.question.value,
                choices: choices,
                usersWhoVoted: [],
                poll_is_open: true,
                time_poll_closed: null
            };
            Polls.insert(newPoll);
        }
    });
}
```